# error in Select Method in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

I created a class for connecting to SQL Server Express. I wrote a method for getting data, but that doesn't work.

I wrote this in my `db` class:

```
public class DB
{
    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Dev\Project\C#\internships\Internships\Internships.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    private SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    public DB()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
    }

    public SqlDataReader select(string query)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
             return dr; 

        con.Close();
        return dr;
    }
}
```

I want to get data using above`select` method and comparison with login information in login form.

Please help me... thank you.

Comment: Please post the error you're getting and what is your query?

Comment: What do you mean by _didn't work_ exactly? What is the error message you get?

Comment: i only wrote a method but used this , how to use this method???

Comment: We can't help you unless we have more information about what is not working. Do you get any error messages? What query are you trying to use? etc.

Comment: Also, the select method will leave the connection open if data is returned. Wrap the code in a try catch finally block and close the connection in the finally block.

Comment: You need to instantiate an instance of the DB class and call the select method with a query. P.S. It seems to me your current implementation will be vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: close connection before returning

Comment: Why are you calling if(dr.Read())? Do you want to ignore first record? Then you return reader so I think it is uncesessary.

Comment: BTW, this is a terrible implementation. You have fields which implement `IDiposable` so your class needs to implement it too to do a proper clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Change `SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader();` to `SqlDataReader dr;`
but there is still several serious problems in your code:

1. When DataReader contains some data then your connection is never closed (connection should be close when you read all data from data reader)
2. You should use SqlParameter to pass parameters to command otherwise someone can use SQL Injection on your code
3. You are using twice Read() method, but after first time you don't care about the result, so you just ignore first record

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code:

```
DB db = new DB();
SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader();
string username = txtUsername.Text;
string pass = txtPassword.Text;
  if (rdoStu.Checked)
    dr=db.select("Select * from tbl_stu where stuId='" + username + "'and mcode='" + pass +"'");
  else if (rdoTch.Checked)
    dr=db.select("select * from tbl_tch where tchId='" + username + "'and mcode='" + pass+"'");
if (dr.Read())
{
  MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
}
```

However, it throws me this error message:

> Error 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors
>   defined

How do I fix it? Where should I start at?

Comment: Remove SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader(); and use var dr = db.select("Select... instead. Also remember to close the connection in db.select.